# How to add and debug a C# file in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm starting out with Unity and trying to use  C# instead of Js - I've not been able to hit a breakpoint in C# yet however the Js hits breakpoints fine. Hopefully someone can see where I've gone wrong

Use dialog to Create a new C# script file which gives me a Start() and Update() method.

I Add some trivial code to Start() and put a breakpoint there

Edit > Project Settings > Script Execution order , and drag the script in the box , click Apply()

I'm not sure that last step does anything - but any tips appreciated!

Using VS2012 w/- UnityVS

Unity 4.3.3

Comment: did you attach the script to a game object for it to run?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing which got it working - add an answer for me to mark if you wish